# How do I stop the mantel over my gas fireplace from getting way too hot?

Tags: fireplace

Can anybody tell me how to redirect the heat from going up to coming out the front? The wall and mantel gets so hot that we can't touch it, so we can't use our fireplace.

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: A photo or two might be useful. Is the flue open?

Answer (score 1):

Most gas fireplace inserts can be fitted with a circulating fan:

[http://www.amazon.com/Electric-Fireplace-Replacement-Blower-brands/dp/B005CFLE30](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CFLE30)

That said, while your mantle may be getting too hot to touch, it (hopefully) was installed per manufacturer instructions and to code.